# Posting a video in Facebook through android by using HttpPost

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-post

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to develop my own APIs regarding facebook.

I have succeeded to some extent but I have a problem in posting data like videos, comments, photos etc. Can anyone please tell me how to write that using HttpPost and OutputStream.

```
HttpPost mPost=new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token="+URLEncoder.encode(access_token)+"&"+"message="+URLEncoder.encode("hii folks"));
HttpClient mClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse mResp=mClient.execute(mPost);
HttpEntity mEnt=mResp.getEntity();
InputStream is=mEnt.getContent();
Log.w("Response post my status message",convertStreamToString(is));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-invent the wheel: just use RestFB (at http://restfb.com/). It is quite frankly the next best thing to sliced bread as far as Java/Facebook interaction.

This is publishing a photo:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
  getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cat.png"), Parameter.with("message", "Test cat"));
```

You can do exactly the same thing with `me/videos` to publish a video. It will not handle type conversion of the video file for you but I believe Facebook takes care of that.

Comment: no.. i cant use them.. i have to build my own API's. ok can u tell me facebook provides data in xml/JSON completely?

Comment: If you insist you have to write your own, then yes: you can use standard HTTP and a JSON parser to do it. Just look at the documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for the underlying details.

Comment: yes im using HttpPost methods to post the content but when it comes to posting a video im not able to do it . I ll post the code for posting a wall post. Can u Pls let me knw how 2 do video posting?